# Fill textarea using jquery, php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a select option and I  want to fill the textarea on select option change using jquery.

this is my code:

```
<html><head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getvalues() {
    var txt = $("textaera[name='txt']:text").val(); 

    $.ajax({ url: "demo_test6.php",
        data: {"txt":txt},
        type: 'get',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(output) {
            console.log(output);
            $("textarea#txt").text(output[0]);
        }
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="demo_test6.php">
        <label for="ctlJob">Job Function:</label>
        <select name="id" id="ctlJob"  onblur="getvalues() " onchange="getvalues()">
            <option value="none" selected="selected">-- Select One --</option>
            <option value="1">Managers</option>
            <option value="2">Team Leaders</option>
            <option value="3">Developers</option>
        </select>

    <textarea nama="txt" id="txt">
        return value should be here
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Book" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP (demo_test.php)

```
<?php

include 'Connect.php';  //Connection to database
$personid=$_GET['id'];
$requete = mysql_query("SELECT shortinfo FROM person where personid='$personid'");
$rownmbr = mysql_numrows($requete);
for ($i=0; $i<$rownmbr; $i++) {
    echo $result = mysql_result($requete,$i);
    $response = array('$result'); // add return data to an array
    echo json_encode($response); // json encode that array
}

exit;

?>
```

when I select a option on select no things happen on the textarea, I spent four days without finding any solution,

please tell me if there is a mistake? or if I need to change or add something in my code!!

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability `id=1' or '1'='1`, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I will correct mysql later , please tell me why textarea don't receive anything when I select a value (select /option)

Comment: $response = array('$result');  this is nonesense first remove the quote second $result is an array try mysql_fetch or $result[0]

Comment: You know you have a typo in the textarea selector, right? Also, you're sending the value of the textarea as the ajax request data payload, not the value of the option you're listening for a change on...

Comment: the button here is useless with this code

Comment: I made this modification 


`<?php`

`include 'Connect.php';  //Connection to database`
`$personid=$_GET['id'];`
`$requete = mysql_query("SELECT shortinfo FROM person where personid=$personid");`
`$rownmbr = mysql_numrows($requete);`

`echo $result = mysql_result($requete,0);`
`echo json_encode($result);`

`exit;`
 
`?>` But I think there is somthing wrong in script

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function(){
  $("select#ctlJob").change(function(){
    $.getJSON("demo_text6.php",{id: $(this).val(), ajax: 'true'}, function(j){
      var options = '';
      
        //options += '<option value="' + j[i].optionValue + '">' + j[i].optionDisplay + '</option>';
      $("#txt").val(optionValue)
      $("textarea#txt").html(options);
    })
  })
})
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have invalid JSON in the server response if you ever have more than 1 DB record as you are JSON-encoding each records individually.

Also, right now, your `echo $result = mysql_result($requete,$i);` is going to automatically create invalid JSON.

For the jQuery JSON parsing to work you must return one and only one valid JSON data structure in your response.

Answer (score 0):

You have sent the value of the textarea instead of the selected option because of the line `var txt = $("textaera[name='txt']:text").val()`

And a rule of thumb for JSON, until you grow familiar with it: build your response data a pure PHP data, and only return it through json_encode after everything is done